# Trigger the Creation of a Specific Preference List?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, plist

I have the following function:

```
hardware_model () {

  local hardware_mod
  hardware_mod=$(defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist 'CPU Names' \
  | cut -sd '"' -f 4 \
  | uniq)

  write_header "Hardware Model" "$hardware_mod"
}
```

which returns, e.g.: `MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014)`.

However, on some machines--running the same OS X version--I get:

```
2018-08-20 11:59:30.331 defaults[25029:3478859] 
The domain/default pair of 
(/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist, CPU 
Names) does not exist .
```

My question is: what **specific** action(s) trigger the creation of: `com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist`? I'd like to be able to create this file reliably in OS X 10.10-10.13 (inclusive), from a terminal, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I was going to answer "first run of /Applications/Utilities/System Information.app", but I've just checked in a recently created user account where I haven't run that app, and ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist exists. So I don't know, but that's one possibility eliminated.

Comment: I forgot to mention: System Information.app used to be called System Profiler - that's why I was considering it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm considering scripting a check, based on the UID, which would search the appropriate path for this info. I'm just not sure that it will always be where I anticipate it will.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still trying to do this, I just figured out how to generate the file on my Mac running Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65).

It's remarkably simple. The file seems to be generated once you select “About This Mac” from the  menu, as shown here:

[image: Apple Menu]

Before that, "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist" did not exist.

After that, I could run

`defaults read "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist" 'CPU Names'`

and get the result I was looking for.

Comment: I'll try on a few machines to see if I can confirm. Perhaps ironically, I am writing a script the mimics the "About this Mac" from a terminal: [https://github.com/marshki/about_dis_mac](https://github.com/marshki/about_dis_mac) .

Comment: Is there a way to trigger this event from a terminal, i.e. without needing to use the GUI?

Comment: None that I have found. Please let me / us know if you find a way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're running your script as root such that `~` expands to `/var/root` instead of a home directory in `/Users`. Unless you've logged into the root account using the GUI, I wouldn't expect that file to exist in root's home folder. You should be able to find the file in a user account which has been logged into.

Comment: On some machines, I can execute the script w/out escalating privileges AND get the desired output. On other machines, I can execute that script with `sudo` and not get the desired output. I am not always clear on when this will happen. What action actually creates this .plist?

Comment: I suppose I could do: `hardware_mod=$(defaults read /Users/$LOGNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist` and get the desired output, except if I am logged in as root?